# How do I add navigation on flutter_spinkit

Tags: android, flutter, dart

How can I make the ***HomeScreen*** load after the ***Spinkit*** . I was able to add the ***spinkit*** loaders on my app, but I am unable to add the navigation in it so that it can runs the home screen automatically,

*Please help*

This is are the codes I have used in the ***spinkit*** page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'package:road_sign/screen/home/home_screen.dart';

class LoadingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoadingPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  void main(List<String> args)  {
    
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green[50],
      body: Center(
        child: SpinKitThreeBounce(
          size: 90,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And these are codes of ***main.dart***

```
import 'package:road_sign/screen/home/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:road_sign/screen/loadingScreen/loadingPage.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Road Sign',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: LoadingPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: did you call any api, if that, then when API is calling your spinkit will show, and when your API call is ended then your desired data will appear with screen.

Comment: No I didn't used any API

Comment: then just use the delay method
 await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `async` method and add a `delay` before navigation.

Please check the below sample :

```dart
class LoadingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoadingPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoadingPageState createState() => _LoadingPageState();
}

class _LoadingPageState extends State<LoadingPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    autoNavigation();
    super.initState();
  }

  void autoNavigation() async {
     // you can change delay here
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => HomeScreen(),
        ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green[50],
      body: Center(
        child: SpinKitThreeBounce(
          size: 90,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It will work, But I suggest using a state management solution to split logic from UI.

Comment: Thank you soo much. Your codes perfectly worked :)